# iOS 11 SpriteKit Game won't go faster than 30 FPS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I am using Xcode beta to update one of my apps for iOS 11. After including some new features to the game, I noticed while testing, the FPS were really low. They were not this low before. I honestly don't know what code to give you guys. Could this just be a problem with the betas? Or is it that I just stuffed to much crap into my game?

My game is only 342MB. It's a 2D game with no 3D rendering at all. The only thing I can think of is that I have too many arc4random's going at once...

Edit: 
This is the code I think is causing the problem

```
    func getCollectable() -> SKSpriteNode {

    var collecatble = SKSpriteNode()

    if Int(randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: 0, secondNum: 9)) == 4 {
        //Come Back
        if GamePlayController.instance.life! < 100 {
            collecatble = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "MonsterRobot")
            collecatble.name = "Monster"
            collecatble.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: collecatble.size)
            collecatble.yScale = 0.09
            collecatble.xScale = 0.09

        }else{
            collecatble.name = "Empty"
        }
    }else{

        collecatble = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Coin2")
        collecatble.name = "Coin2"
        collecatble.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: collecatble.size)

    }
    if Int(randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: 0, secondNum: 100)) == 51 {

        collecatble = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Slow icon")
        collecatble.name = "SlowIcon"
        collecatble.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: collecatble.size)
        collecatble.yScale = 0.05
        collecatble.xScale = 0.05
    }

    collecatble.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    collecatble.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.DarkCloudAndCollectables
    collecatble.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Player
    collecatble.zPosition = 2


    return collecatble

}



 func randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: CGFloat, secondNum: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

    return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX) * abs(firstNum - secondNum) + min(firstNum, secondNum)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using Xcode's performance tools to analyze it?

Comment: Without seeing any code and having no access to your project there isn't anything that anyone can do. Try analysing it with Xcode.

Comment: Using performance tools now!

Comment: Updated my question to include code

Comment: How are you creating the random number? And how often? Is this run every frame?

Comment: I updated my answer so you can see my random number function

Comment: Yes, the random number gets generated every frame

Comment: What does time profiler tell you about which methods are taking the most time?

Comment: Alright! I fixed it, so instead of calling the random number every frame, I changed it to be called every other frame and now the game runs flawlessly. It was because to much code was having to be generated at once I imagine. Thanks for all of yall's help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was an easy fix. Make sure your code is running in the proper order. When generating new sprites as the game is loading, you need to make sure that you have enough memory. Deleting Sprites as they were added fixed my problem.